# pattern rule vs. static pattern rule which one is efficient?

Tags: makefile

I have a doubt that is
if i could write a rule with both pattern rule and static pattern rule
which one is better to write over the other?
does the pattern rule is more fast and efficient?
If there are too many static target list in static pattern rule 
does it can slow down performance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicit rules will always be faster than implicit rules.  Implicit rules include both pattern rules and suffix rules.  Static pattern rules, even though the name seems to imply they are pattern rules, are actually not: they are explicit rules (make internally generates a separate explicit rule for each expanded target in a static pattern rule).

It may be true that the more static pattern targets you have the more memory make will use, and in theory a pattern rule will allow make to match the pattern then free the memory associated with it after the recipe completes which might result in lower memory usage, but I think it would have to be a large number to offset the extra processing needed to match pattern rules.

As always, the only way to know for sure is to test it in your environment.

But my suspicion is that static pattern rules will be faster.

However, for me the more important thing is readability and flexibility... a bit of extra time during `make` is usually nothing in comparison to the amount of time spent in your build by the compiler and linker.  For some very large and complex makefiles, this might not be true of course.